# Hudson failing build w/o revealing cause

Tags: zend-framework, hudson, phpunit, php-5.3, phing

Every build has failed as of Tuesday.  I'm not exactly sure what happened.  The Phing targets (clean/prepare) are being executed properly.  Additionally, the unit tests are passing with flying colors, with only a warning for duplicate code (not a reason for a fail).  I tried removing the phpDoc target to see if that was causing the error, but the build still failed.

> Started by user chris Updating
>   file://localhost/projects/svn/ips-com/trunk
>   At revision 234 no change for
>   file://localhost/projects/svn/ips-com/trunk
>   since the previous build [trunk] $
>   /opt/phing/bin/phing clean prepare
>   -logger phing.listener.NoBannerLogger Buildfile:
>   /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/trunk/build.xml
>
> IPS > clean:
>
> ```
>  [echo] Clean...    [delete] Deleting directory
> ```
>
> /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build
>
> IPS > prepare:
>
> ```
>  [echo] Prepare...
> [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build
> [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build/logs
> [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build/logs/coverage
> [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build/logs/coverage-html
> [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build/docs
> [mkdir] Created dir: /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build/app
> ```
>
> BUILD FINISHED
>
> Total time: 1.0244 second
>
> [workspace] $ /bin/bash -xe
>   /tmp/hudson3259012225710915845.sh
>   + cd trunk/tests
>   + /usr/local/bin/phpunit --verbose -d memory_limit=512M --log-junit
>   ../../build/logs/phpunit.xml
>   --coverage-clover ../../build/logs/coverage/clover.xml
>   --coverage-html ../../build/logs/coverage-html/
>   PHPUnit 3.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> IPS  Default_IndexControllerTest  .
>
> Default_AuthControllerTest  ......
>
> Manage_UsersControllerTest  .....
>   testDeleteInvalidUserId   ..
>       testGetPermissionsForInvalidUserId   ..    Audit_OverviewControllerTest 
>   ............
>
> Time: 14 seconds, Memory: 61.00Mb
>
> [30;42m[2KOK (28 tests, 198
>   assertions) [0m[2K Writing code
>   coverage data to XML file, this may
>   take a moment.
>
> Generating code coverage report, this
>   may take a moment.
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Unknown: Error occured while
>   closing statement in Unknown on line 0
>   [workspace] $ /bin/bash -xe
>   /tmp/hudson1439023061736436000.sh
>   + /usr/local/bin/phpcpd --log-pmd ./build/logs/cpd.xml ./trunk phpcpd
>   1.3.2 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> Found 1 exact clones with 6 duplicated
>   lines in 2 files:
>
> - library/Ips/Form/Decorator/SplitInput.php:8-14
>     library/Ips/Form/Decorator/FeetInches.php:10-16
>
> 0.04% duplicated lines out of 16585 total lines of code.
>
> Time: 4 seconds, Memory: 19.50Mb [DRY]
>   Skipping publisher since build result
>   is FAILURE Publishing Javadoc [xUnit]
>   [INFO] - Starting to record. [xUnit]
>   [WARNING] - Can't create the path
>   /var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/generatedJUnitFiles.
>   Maybe the directory already exists.
>   [xUnit] [INFO] - Processing
>   PHPUnit-3.4 (default) [xUnit] [INFO] -
>   [PHPUnit-3.4 (default)] - 1 test
>   report file(s) were found with the
>   pattern 'build/logs/phpunit.xml'
>   relative to
>   '/var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace'
>   for the testing framework 'PHPUnit-3.4
>   (default)'. [xUnit] [INFO] -
>   Converting
>   '/var/lib/hudson/.hudson/jobs/IPS/workspace/build/logs/phpunit.xml'
>   . [xUnit] [INFO] - Stopping recording.
>   Publishing Clover coverage report...
>   Publishing Clover XML report...
>   Publishing Clover coverage results...
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Seems that it's failing when writing out code coverage results. Have you tried to build this job without executing code coverage?

Comment: Yes, I've narrowed it down to the Copy & Paste detector, which I did not expect.  PHPUnit/Code Coverage work fine.  Removing phpcpd allows the build to complete successfully.

Comment: Strange, but at least you can get builds out the door.

Answer (score 2):

What changed since Tuesday? Try to manually run exactly the same commands that Hudson tries to run from the same directory that Hudson starts it from (usually the jobs workspace directory). Of course with the user account that Hudson is started under.

There are several possibilities. ranging from standard groups for a directory, to permission, or other things outside of Hudson. Was Hudson upgraded? Was a plugin upgraded? Was the OS or php upgraded? Was there a change in the default or user .profile or .env (or the equivalent files)? Does another process accesses the workspace? ......

Once I had the problem that all of the sudden my deployment scripts did not run anymore. The mystery was, that I could still run the script from command line with the Hudson user account. The reason was simple but took a while to uncover. There was a java upgrade from 5 to 6. Both versions were available. After comparing the environment variables, there was a difference in the path. The problem was that the new path was set in the global .profile. But Hudson does not open an interactive shell, therefore the .profile will not be executed. If you have a problem like this, you can put the initialization in the .env file (or whatever the filename is for your system), because this will be run regardless if it is a interactive shell or not. Alternatively you can configure Hudson to set it on master or node/slave level.

Comment: The Copy and Paste Detector causes the issue, but the CPD XML file is generated and processed perfectly.  It makes no sense!

Comment: I had issues getting Phing to work with PHPUnit due to apparent environment issues, but gave up and ended up executing shell commands instead of executing PHPUnit via Phing.  While I did find /etc/profile, I did not see any .env files.  I use CentOS 5.5 w/ WHM/cPanel.

Comment: With a little bit googling I found that there should be a file /etc/environment. However, I can not guaranty for anything, because I have never used centos

Comment: I just googled a little bit more and there is the file /etc/bashrc So you need to find out what shell Hudson is starting (is it bash or does centos provides other shells as well). Then you can find out what files are executed when starting this shell. Pay close attention to non-interactive and non-login differences of the shell.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a command to not break the 'build' as a failure you have to add #! in front of the command to prevent the flags -xe which produce this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  That will certainly come in handy in instances where I want to turn off specific failures.